# RxJava2 call onNext Consumer twice after rotation

Tags: java, android, retrofit2, android-orientation, rx-java2

Have a very simple `Activity` wherein I try to learn `rx`.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SampleApi sampleApi;

    private Observable<Post> postObservable;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Timber.plant(new Timber.DebugTree());

        sampleApi = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com")
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .client(buildOkHttpClient())
                .build()
                .create(SampleApi.class);

        findViewById(R.id.subscribe1).setOnClickListener(
                target -> sampleApi.getPost(1)
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                        .subscribe(this::handleResponse)
        );
    }

    @NonNull
    private OkHttpClient buildOkHttpClient() {
        // build some okhttp3 client here
    }

    private void handleResponse(Post post) {
        Timber.i("handleResponse: " + post.id);
    }
}
```

It works ok, but when I rotate my device (from portrait to landscape) and after that click button, my `handleResponse` method is called twice. So if I rotate my device twice, `handleResponse` is called three times and so on (network request is always single).

Can't understand the problem.

---

**Update**

I understood my problem, this is not about `rx`, this is about `Timber`, when I rotate screen, activity is recreated each time and `Timber` add new `Tree` to `Forest`. So when I log something it output twice.

Comment: Activity is re-created each time you rotate so, as I understand it at least, a new subscription is created each time.  The solution I believe is to ensure you unsubscribe at appropriate activity lifecycle event (would recommend using `https://github.com/trello/RxLifecycle`)

Comment: what returns `Timber.i("handleResponse: " + post.id + ",  Activity:" + this);`

Comment: @JohnO'Reilly, but if i understand correctly I create subscription only when I click the button, not before, not when activity is created or recreated

Comment: @Selvin it returns `handleResponse: 1, Activity:rx.test.MainActivity@4ecfb9e
handleResponse: 1, Activity:rx.test.MainActivity@4ecfb9e`

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're not unsubscribing when the activity gets destroyed.

MainActivity:

```
Disposable postDisposable;
```

onCreate:

```
findViewById(R.id.subscribe1).setOnClickListener(....

    ....

    if (postDisposable != null) {
        postDisposable.dispose(); 
    }

    postDisposable = sampleApi.getPost(1)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleResponse, throwable -> Log.e("TAG", "Error", throwable));
```

onDestroy:

```
if (postDisposable != null) {
    postDisposable.dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I know about Subscriptions. But first of all I use rxjava2 and `subscribe` method returns Disposable. But even with your code (where I replaced Subscription to Disposable) it not works.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't notice you were using rxjava 2. I believe the reason is the same, you still need to unsubscribe in `onDestroy`. Check my edit.

Comment: Nope, there is no effect. Do you have some assumptions?

Comment: Next time attach a breakpoint and use a debugger to make sure it gets called once.